# JSON and Adding multiple markers to map

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I've been searching around but I think I need personal help. I have a variable named "FriendsList" which contains 3 names, "Andrew", "Bro", "Jeremy". I am trying to go through each name and get that persons longitude and latitude and add it to the map. 
So far, I have this, but I believe the JSON is wrong because of the errors that I am getting.

```
     for(int i =0; i < FriendsList.size(); i++)
                {
                                        //start the post to the database
                    String responseBody1 = null;
                    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    httpPost = new HttpPost("http://skyrealmstudio.com/GetSpecificUserLocation.php");

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    String friendToFind = FriendsList.get(i).toString();
                    nameValuePair1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", friendToFind));


                    try {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        responseBody1 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        // writing response to log
                        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //end the post response

                    //JSON the string that is got from the post.
                     jsonStr = responseBody1;

                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
                    if (jsonStr != null){
                        jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


                        JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                       tempMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE))))
                                .title(friendToFind)
                                .snippet(c.getString(TAG_COMMENTS));
                        markers.add(i, tempMarker);
                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void Result)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < FriendsList.size(); i++)
        {
            googleMap.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(markers.get(i).getTitle())
                    .position(new LatLng(markers.get(i).getPosition().latitude, markers.get(i).getPosition().longitude)));
        }
    }
```

The errors that I am getting from this snippet of code are as follows:

```
      6882-6882/com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp, PID: 6882
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp.MainActivity$getFriendsList.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:631)
        at com.skyrealm.brockyy.findmypeepsapp.MainActivity$getFriendsList.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:520)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I notice that the error says index 1 is an invalid index which is what makes me believe it is parsing incorrectly or something.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < FriendsList.size(); i++)
    { 
        googleMap.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(markers.get(i).getTitle())
                .position(new LatLng(markers.get(i).getPosition().latitude, markers.get(i).getPosition().longitude)));
    }
```

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++)
    { 
        googleMap.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(markers.get(i).getTitle())
                .position(new LatLng(markers.get(i).getPosition().latitude, markers.get(i).getPosition().longitude)));
    }
```

Comment: yes that's why you are getting this exception. As in loop it will execute 0 10 2 and marker size is 1 so for i value 1 and 2 it will show "IndexOutOfBoundsException".

Comment: Correct, I was hoping to get some help in correcting this issue.